R parallelly error when creating nested futures
I'm upgrading some code from older R versions to 4.4 and encountered some problem with the newer versions.
This used to run perfectly with 4.1 and older versions of future and parallelly.
In another install with R 4.3 and future version 1.33.2 and parallelly 1.34 it still works too.
library(future)
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()
plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 4), tweak(multisession, workers = 5)), gc = TRUE)
foreach(i = c(1,2,3) %dopar% {
  foreach(j = c(3,4,5) %dopar% {
    return(i + j)
  }
}

In the newer version with parallelly 1.38 it fails with the following error:
Error in checkNumberOfLocalWorkers(workers) :
  Attempting to set up 5 localhost parallel workers with only 1 CPU cores available for this R process (per 'mc.cores'), which could result in a 500% load. The hard limit is set to 300%. Overusing the CPUs has negative impact on the current R process, but also on all other processes of yours and others running on the same machine. See help("parallelly.options", package = "parallelly") for how to override the soft and hard limits

When using
foreach(i = c(1,2,3)) %dopar% {
  future::nrofWorkers()
}

it correctly returns 5 so this seems to be a bug in the package?
I have tried setting the parallelly.availableCores.methods option but didn't have any success.
Any ideas on how to fix this for now?

The docs suggest you need to use plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 4), tweak(multisession, workers = I(5)))) to override the protection against recursive parallelism. Perhaps it used to not raise an error, but silently convert the inner loop to sequential processing?

It indeed looks like this extra protection was added in parallelly v1.37.0, but the As-Is I() syntax should avoid this.

Wonderful, thank you.  For some reason didn't occur to me to check the newer future documentation, just checked the parallelly docs.
It definitely did nest the parallel cores before, found some github issue where they talked about implementing a check like that in future versions. Doesn't seem like a great way to do it, in how it's done now.
